# can two html pages be controlled by the same button

Tags: javascript, html

I need two html pages to be controlled by the same button so if you click button1 on the first html, I need a msg to be displayed on the second html page that button1 was clicked and it's the same thing for button2

Comment: The answer is no, but more importantly, why would you want that?

Comment: There two separate HTML pages so answer is no... however if you were to capture/save either through a server request or through local storage on the browser you could do so.

Comment: you have to look into websocket kind of implementation, if I understand correctly you want to implement something similar to realtime/chat app functionality. Look into scoket.js or SignalR.

Comment: the storage API or IndexedDB should work for this. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES... *kind of*... Presuming both pages reside on the same domain, you can essentially do the equivalent "long polling" as Jordan Davis' answer discussed, but you can use Local Storage for that.

For example, consider the following code (untested, but just giving a general idea):

```
<script type="application/javascript">
        function CheckForMessages(){
            var msg = window.localStorage.getItem("Message_From_Page_1");
            if(msg !== null){
                document.getElementById("SomeIdWhereYouWantMessage").innerHTML = msg;

                // Acknowledge and clear item from local storage, to avoid
                // double processing:
                window.localStorage.removeItem("Message_From_Page_1");
            }

            window.setTimeout(function(){CheckForMessages()}, 100); // check again in 100 ms
        }

        document.onload = CheckForMessages();
</script>
```

Likewise, page 1 would have similar code to receive data persisted by page 2.

Generally, in my opinion, this shouldn't be a desired approach, but yes, it is possible to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO, they are two separate HTML pages which load synchronously (meaning on load-time) to have anything update based on some trigger on one of the pages you would have to use sockets for "truly" LIVE updates to the page, or use a technique called "long polling" which uses a daemon (background process) to check for updates and push the changes to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Why answer with a no? 
Yes you can, depending on browser. Their is a shared worker feature in the likes of chrome and FF (not ie). It's an area of processing space which is at a higher level than a tab/page - but within the browser. 
So if you open page 1, it creates the SW, then page 2 loads it has access to this SW. Both pages register with said SW so that you can now write code so if page 1 needs to send a message to page 2 or visa versa then it can.
If both pages load at exactly same time and try to create same SW, the browser so sorts it so no worries about race conditions and the like.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker